# Loop returning more values than expected and NA's

Tags: r, simulation

I'm trying to simulate some data for sample size estimation and my loop is returning unexpected results.

I'm trying to sample a from a vector of generated values with varying numbers of sample sizes and then concatenate means and standard deviations for a number of simulations.

```
library(MCMCglmm)
library(tidyverse)

Est <- function(n, mean, sd, lower, upper, samp_min, samp_max, samp_int, nsim){

        Data <- round(rtnorm(n, mean, sd, lower, upper), digits = 0) # Create a vector to sample from

        Samp_size <- seq(samp_min, samp_max, samp_int) # Create vector of sample sizes

        # Set up enpty results data frames
        Results_samp <- data.frame()
        Results <- data.frame()

        for(i in 1:nsim){ ## Loop through number of simulations

        for (j in seq_along(Samp_size)) { # Loop through sample sizes
                Score <- sample(Data, j, replace = TRUE)
                Nsubj <- Samp_size[j]
                Mean <- mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)
                SD <- sd(Score, na.rm = TRUE)
                Results_samp <- rbind(Results_samp, 
                                      data.frame(
                                              Nsubj,
                                              Mean,
                                              SD))
        }
        Results <- rbind(Results, Results_samp)   
        }

        Results
}

Test <- Est(n = 1000, mean = 55, sd = 37, lower = 0, upper = 100, 
            samp_min = 5, samp_max = 20, samp_int = 5, nsim = 5)
```

This creates a data frame with 60 rows, where I'm expecting 20 (5 simulations of 4 sample sizes) and I always get NA returned for the sample size of 5.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to "reset" `Results_samp` in your inner `for` loop. I've given an example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, dynamically growing a `data.frame` with `rbind` is a *very* inefficient way of doing things in R. There are almost always better/faster ways of doing what you're trying to do.

That aside, in terms of answering your question, let's take a look at a simplified version of your nested `for` loop

```
x1 <- data.frame()
x2 <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:5) {
    for (j in 1:4) x1 <- rbind(x1, data.frame(x1 = i, x2 = i^2))
    x2 <- rbind(x2, x1)
}
```

See how `x2` has 60 rows?

The reason for that is that you never reset `x1`. If we fix that

```
x1 <- data.frame()
x2 <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:5) {
    for (j in 1:4) x1 <- rbind(x1, data.frame(x1 = i, x2 = i^2))
    x2 <- rbind(x2, x1)
    x1 <- data.frame()
}
```

we have `nrow(x2) = 20`, as expected.

Comment: Thanks!
Any idea why sd is always NA with a sample size of 5?
Are you able to suggest an alternative to rbind?

Comment: @JLC `SD` will be `NA` if you have only a single entry, which will happen in the first step of your inner `j` loop. Are you sure this code bit is correct: `Score <- sample(Data, j, replace = TRUE)`? You are sampling `j` samples, which takes values `1:4`; perhaps you meant `sample(Data, Samp_size[j], replace = T)`?

Comment: As to optimising the code: If you must use a loop, use nested `lapply` (which is a `for` loop in disguise), returning a nested `list`; then `rbind` once (instead of at every step of the loop). Better yet, use vectorised operations (which will depend on the functions).

Comment: Thanks!! I did intend to have `sample(Data, Samp_size[j], replace = T)`!
Thanks for the vectorization suggestion as well; I'll see if I can convert this function. With a large number of replications, this one takes ages.

Comment: @JLC You're very welcome. Another thing you may want to consider is to post your code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Since you have a working and reproducible piece of code, you may want to ask there for possible code optimisations. They've got an R code tag as well:-)